# Vuejs Slot Parent Child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do I get these 2 components to work together?

```
Vue.component('parent', {
    template: ''+
        '<slot name="foo"></slot>'+
    ''
});

Vue.component('child', {
    template: ''+
        '<div slot="foo">bar</div>'+
    ''
});
```

I thought I could do something like this but it didn't appear to work

```
Vue.component('parent', {
    components: [
        'child'
    ],
    template: ''+
        '<slot name="foo"></slot>'+
    ''
});
```

Here is a JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fjmLL52/

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I've added a JS Fiddle... sorry I am pretty new to vue still

Comment: Do you want the child to be rendered inside the parent?

Comment: Yes I want the slot or "template" to be in the parent as like a place holder and then the contents of the child to be dumped in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the child to be rendered in the parent, the template would look like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <main>
        <parent>
          <child slot="foo"></child>
        </parent>
    </main>
</div>
```

You also can remove the `slot="foo"` from the child template.

```
Vue.component('child', {
    template: `<div>bar</div>`
});
```

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
    template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="foo">Default</slot>
      <h1><slot name="bar">Header</slot>
    </div>`
});

Vue.component('child', {
    template: '' +
        '<div>bar</div>' +
 ''
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <main>
        <parent>
          <child slot="foo"></child>
          <span slot="bar">Header Content</span>
        </parent>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I have multiple slots that are being set then i'd want to keep `slot="foo"` right?

Comment: Ok i tried updating my JS Fiddle but I must be missing something https://jsfiddle.net/3fjmLL52/1/

Comment: Yes multiple slots because the child will have content that will be set in different places within the template

Comment: @BanningStuckey Are there multiple lots in the child, or in the parent? I updated the answer with an example of multiple slots for the parent.

Comment: Both... please let me know if this is not the vue way but on my current path its both.

Comment: ok I got my js fiddle to work like I am expecting... slot can not be a root element https://jsfiddle.net/3fjmLL52/2/

Comment: spoke to soon... surely I am making this harder than it is https://jsfiddle.net/3fjmLL52/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154269/discussion-between-bert-and-banning-stuckey).